# Shift with 64 bit int

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, shift

I have a __int64 variable `x = 0x8000000000000000`.

I try to shift it right by byte : `x >> 4`

I`ve thought that the result should be `0x0800000000000000`, but unfortunately I get `0xf800000000000000`.

I use VS10. Why is it so? And how can I solve that?

Comment: You should read about [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).  It looks like you probably want an unsigned value - `__uint64`, I guess?

Comment: @CarlNorum - is it legal to define 0x8000000000000000 as unsigned?- it has MSB = 1

Comment: `0x8000000000000000`, like all hexadecimal literals, is by definition unsigned to begin with.  Your assignment/initialization is converting it to signed.

Comment: @CarlNorum That's not quite correct, the type of a hexadecimal or octal constant without suffix is the first of `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int` in which the value of the constant can be represented (if any). `0x8000000000000000` will usually have type `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`, though.

Comment: @Daniel - right.  Sorry, I had remembered that wrong.  In this case, it is almost certain to be unsigned as you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because shifting signed numbers is only defined by the language if the left operand is at least 0. In your case I assume it's a twos-complement representation and your number is negative making the result unspecified (or implementation-defined, I don't have the reference at hand right now). Typically you would either get a logical shift or an arithmetic shift.

If you can get away with making your variable unsigned that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

try to use `__uint64 variable x = 0x8000000000000000`

I think you can declare it this way as well:

```
u64 x = 0x8000000000000000;
```

`x >> 4` you will give you:

```
0x0800000000000000
```

see for more info where the `F` came [from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) in the MSBs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is an easy one. :)

Your number is signed. With the first bit being set, it is negative. Thus, in order to keep it negative, it is filled with 1s.

I would assume casting it to unsigned and then shifting it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a negative number. Use (or convert to) unsigned before the shift.

Comment: is it legal to define 0x8000000000000000 as unsigned?- it has MSB = 1 (negative number)

Answer (score 1):

Signed values are shifted right by sign bit and unsigned by zero:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __int64  signedval;
    unsigned __int64  unsignedval;

    signedval=0x8000000000000000 >> 4;
    unsignedval=0x8000000000000000 >> 4;

        printf(" Signed %x  , unsigned %x   \n", signedval, unsignedval);

        getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
Signed 0  , unsigned 8000000
```

Comment: The bit that comes in from the left on a signed int is implementation defined.  It is not guaranteed to maintain the sign.  Shifting an unsigned to the right is guaranteed to slide in zeros, but shifting a signed to the right could slide in either zero or the sign bit.