# performing bit-wise AND with int and shifting

Tags: c++, bit, shift, negative-number

This question is based on:
[Shift with 64 bit int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614877/shift-with-64-bit-int/14616081#14616081)
The origin of the question is - I define an `enum` ,which presents different masks.
And need to make `&` of the variable with `enum` (mask) after that shift the result right.
Since `enum` type is always `int`,the variable was defined also as `int`.But as you can see there is a problem shifting right negative numbers.
what can be done to solve that?

Comment: Why can't you just define the variable as `uint64_t`?

Comment: I think he wants to shift a value of enumeration.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - I want to shift the result after AND.

Comment: You could make the underlying type of the enum different.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain - I defined it is int64_t to be in consistency with   int (enum mask)

Comment: @chris - sounds good - how?-static_cast from int to uint64_t?The compiler will cry!

Comment: @Yakov, `enum MyEnum : unsigned {};` would make it use unsigned members.

Comment: Unless you need more than 32 bits, I'd avoid `long long`.  If you are using C++11, and can force the type, use `uint_least32_t` (or whatever you need).  But in all cases, use (or cast to) an unsigned integral type---such bit manipulations are _why_ C and C++ have unsigned types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `enum` type is not always `int`; in C++11, you can
even force it to be an unsigned type.  And second, even when the
underlying type is `int`, you can (and should) freely cast to
and from `unsigned` with no real risk.  You can, for example, overload
the `operator&` thusly:

```
MyEnum
operator&( MyEnum lhs, MyEnum rhs )
{
    return static_cast<MyEnum>(
        static_cast<unsigned>( lhs) & static_cast<unsigned>( rhs ) );
}
```

For extracting fields that may be in the middle somewhere:

```
int
getFieldX( MyEnum values )
{
    return static_cast<unsigned>(values & fieldXMask) >> fieldXOffset;
}
```

This will ensure correct behavior (and once the unsigned value
has been shifted, it should convert to `int` without loss of
value).

Comment: @Yackov I don't either.  I've been using code like the above for over twenty years.  (If you really want to play it safe, cast to <code>uint_least<i>n</i>_t</code>, rather than `unsigned`.  But for most purposes, `unsigned` is sufficient.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you static cast the value of the enumeration to `unsigned long long` before shifting. I think this is the safest option you can use.

Comment: It's the safest, but it could involve a significant performance hit if the machine hardware doesn't support 64 bit types, and your enums don't require them.

Comment: For various values of 'significant'.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the shift first, then AND against the shifted mask, to work around this.